# How can I increase performance of the active record iteration (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have the following code, but it takes approximately 3 minutes to process 1000 records. In production I am expecting to have 1 000 000 of records and this performance is unacceptable to process such amount of records. Any idea how to make this faster? I am new with Rails, so still learning the things on the go.

In the example below, I am trying to iterate all products for given supplier and if the product item_id is not in the xml feed, include the product id into array which I will be iterating in the next step and marking the products as "archived / inactive". The problem is mainly with the first part of the code, which takes too much time to process.

```
self.products.where( :archived => false ).find_each do |p|
   archive = !@xml_feed.css("ITEM_ID").to_s.downcase.include?("<item_id>#{p.item_id}</item_id>")
   archived_product_ids << p.id if archive
end

if archived_product_ids.size > 0
   # update all archived products
   Product.where('id IN (?)', archived_product_ids).update_all( :archived => true, :archived_at => Time.now, :active => false )
   logger.info "Products #{archived_product_ids.to_s} has been archived and deactivated."
end
```

This is the output in my console where you can see 3 minutes between processing each 1000 records:

```
[2015-08-31T22:28:18.090063 #28332] DEBUG -- :   Product Load (5.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."supplier_id" = $1 AND "products"."archived" = $2  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000  [["supplier_id", 2], ["archived", "f"]]

[2015-08-31T22:31:14.767496 #28332] DEBUG -- :   Product Load (5.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."supplier_id" = $1 AND "products"."archived" = $2 AND ("products"."id" > 2513)  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000  [["supplier_id", 2], ["archived", "f"]]
```

Comment: What's taking all the time?

Comment: Are you seeing the update statement in your logs?  Indexes that run after?

Comment: You might want to give Activerecord-import a try: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would start with assigning the complex expression to a variable, so it is only calculated once, and using pluck to avoid instantiating all of those product objects:

```
item_ids = @xml_feed.css("ITEM_ID").to_s.downcase
self.products.where( :archived => false ).pluck(:id, :item_id) do |p|
  archive = !item_ids.include?("<item_id>#{p[1]}</item_id>")
  archived_product_ids << p[0] if archive
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting your search. You are drawing out all of the records, and looking for ids in @xml_feed. Why don't you try drawing out all ids in @xml_feed and then, querying for those in the database?

If there are on the order of 100 items in @xml_feed, for example, you can let the database do all of the searching amongst a million records for matching ids, in the query, which is what the database is good at.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for so valuable tips. I was able to reduce the time to process 1 000 records from 3 minutes to 5 seconds, which is perfect! Every supplier has as average around 8k records and different xml feed source, so I can run a cron job to update products for each supplier separately on daily basis now. This should be complete within 1.5h for all (1 million) and one worker, which is acceptable.

```
# archive products if they are not present in the xml feed
item_ids = @xml_feed.css("ITEM_ID").to_s
self.products.where( :archived => false ).pluck(:id, :item_id).each do |p|
    archive = !item_ids.include?("<ITEM_ID>#{p[1]}</ITEM_ID>")
    if archive
        archived_product_ids << p[0]
        archived_products += 1
        new_import_record.update_attributes(archived_products: archived_products)
    end
end
```